# Allowing Admins to edit Pod Templates on a Network/MultiSite install

Tags: pods-framework

For a client I'm running Pods WP Networks install. A multisite Administrator reports that she can't edit any of the Pod Templates (found under `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=_pods_template`).

I can edit these as a Network Super-Admin, but she can't as a Site Administrator.

Is there a way to allow the Admin to edit her Pod Templates without prompting her to a SuperAdmin temporarily)?

Comment: See this https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/3985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the capability of all adminstrators to use Pods in putting this code in a plugin :

```
add_filter("pods_admin_capabilities", function ($pods_admin_capabilities, $cap) {

    $pods_admin_capabilities[] = "administrator";

    return $pods_admin_capabilities;

}, 10, 2);
```